# Principal Component Analysis problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure this is the right place but here I go:

I have a database of 300 picture in high-resolution.
I want to compute the PCA on this database and so far here is what I do:
- reshape every image as a single column vector
- create a matrix of all my data (500x300)
- compute the average column and substract it to my matrix, this gives me X
- compute the correlation C = X'*X (300x300)
- find the eigenvectors V and Eigen Values D of C.
- the PCA matrix is given by X*V*D^-1/2, where each column is a Principal Component

This is great and gives me correct component.

Now what I'm doing is doing the same PCA on the same database, except that the images have a lower resolution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOzvy.png

Here are my results, low-res on the left and high-res on the right.
Has you can see most of them are similar but SOME images are not the same (the ones I circled)

Is there any way to explain this? I need for my algorithm to have the same images, but one set in high-res and the other one in low-res, how can I make this happen?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis vectors produced by PCA won't necessarily be in the same order after downsampling the training set, because high-frequency features won't be considered. If you need a 1:1 mapping, downsample the basis vectors themselves, rather than the training set. The resultant basis vectors won't be ordered by importance anymore, but that may not matter to you.